# Why does GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() return null when I use OpenIDConnect to authenticate?

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, openid-connect

I am having a really hard time getting OpenIDConnect to work properly with this asp.net 4.6 mvc 5 project. Recently I was getting a 404 error and ended up adding a custom route to the callback action to get it to work past that. AFter that I started getting a error about GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returning null and getting a nullreferenceexception. This is what my config looks like with some things redacted, along with the routing. Also the image provided is one of the errors I get,if i dont use custom routing i just get a 404 error.

OpenIdConnect nonce cookie is there, also in the URL it is sending the state and the code

```
https://localhost:44348/signin-oidc/?code=e33dab0ae5e9640ef731c460180780092703727b&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D-JlLC-VdZi-KZst8OY4JikRrl59vm19HATAcOaqUv8a22U8ch9gC_IJARHlsvaDKZQrqfeTewtdk5d-KcZSrUR3qCoJVcmzNRDP8C0JJ2NH9ql42J3H1xkxEzoAvJ0wxITy-tCj5H-N-bYhMZbO4kB8s2S4msCF0kEDzgipoPmGfZfreUeyYcerwK_OJGH3uYKUYa1NjqA0G-hlhiYpUj8DUp59EXpDz6sr1wtohTiI
```

[image]

Code

```
var json = "";
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            json = wc.DownloadString("http://orders.data443.com/oauth/openid-configuration.php");
        }

        var settings = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://orders.data443.com/oauth/",
            ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44348/signin-oidc/",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc/"),
            Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration(json),
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
            },
            Scope = "openid email profile"
        };
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(settings);
```

Routing

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "signin-oidc",
        url: "signin-oidc",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ExternalLoginCallback" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently dealt with these issues as well. There is an incompatibility between OWIN and ASP.NET pre-Core where cookies set by the OWIN middleware are obliterated by System.Web. Microsoft has provided some workarounds, but there's "No Cure-all" (read through the [wiki](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/System.Web-response-cookie-integration-issues)!). You need to use one of their ICookieManager implementations that uses the System.Web.HttpContextBase object model to prevent cookie conflicts.

```
...
CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
...
```

Make sure you use it throughout OWIN. You'll probably at least set it in `CookieAuthenticationOptions` and `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` and you'll need to replace `app.UseExternalSignInCookie()` with something like this:

```
// app.UseExternalSignInCookie();
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
     AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
     AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
     CookieName = ".AspNet." + DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
     ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
     CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
});
```

Wiki:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/System.Web-response-cookie-integration-issues

Bugs:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170912171644/https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/197
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/331